# DevExpress vs Telerik ASP.NET Controls

Tags: asp.net, telerik, devexpress

Hello DevExpress and Telerik users,

I know there are lot of questions out there re DevExpress vs Telerik ASP.NET controls (grid, editors and scheduler) but a specific questions here:

**Performance - which one is faster?**

Thanks,

SJ

Comment: Been thinking about this myself. I've been using dev express for a little while now. Never used Telerik so I'd be eager to see what people have to say as well.

Comment: You should be more specific - which platform are you interested in? Is it ASP.NET, HTML5(JavaScript), Winforms, WPF/SL, etc.

Comment: This question is too general. Most of controls are server side binded and performance is heavily related to server side code. We can talk about client side rendering, size of html controls generate, size of control javascript, grid handling of small/medium/large amount of data. I doubt that Telerik or DevExpress is superior in all areas and in all types of applications. But, if you want superficial answer to superficial question here it is: "go to asp.net DevEx / Telerik demo sites and try for yourself".

Comment: Which exactly performance you are interested in (grid, editors, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. I am more interested in ASP.NET grid and editor controls. @Filip, DevExpress demo site use ms access databases so very hard to know about performance, I am after view from people who might have used both products.